# Accessing the information in build.settings through an ajax request

Tags: ajax, extjs, sencha-touch-2

So I know you can use json files to [load data into a store](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Ajax), but I was wondering if there exists a way to make a request to only access a single "variable", in a similar way `Ux.Locale.Manager` works.

To be more specific, I'm working with an app built on Sencha Architect, and I would like one of the views to contain the version of the app. While I could just hardcode that label and update it every time I make a build, I was wondering if it was possible to just access the information in the `build.settings` file, specifically the `versionString` and `versionCode` variables, to make things easier? And if possible, how would I go about making an ajax request without involving a `Model` and a `Store`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I kept thinking I had to make a call with an `AjaxProxy`, but a simple `Ext.Ajax.request` did the trick:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: 'build.settings',
    method: 'GET',
    success: function(response, opts){
        var data = JSON.parse(response.responseText);
        Ext.getCmp('appVersion').setHtml("version " + data.androidBuild.versionString + "." + data.androidBuild.versionCode);
    }
});
```